# Difficulty finding complex roots of an equation

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I have been presented with the following question:

given that $(2-i)$ and $(1+3i)$ are roots of the equation $$ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0$$ find the other two roots.

---

I am not sure where to begin on this question, any help with the methodology to find the solution would be greatly appreciated.

here is the exact question:

[image]

Comment: Assuming there is a comma between $(2-i)$ and $(3-i)$, there is no way to determine the other two roots, without some constraints on the **complex** values of $a,b,c,d,e$.

Comment: Same as above, with "$(1+3i)$" instead of "$(3-i)$". Pick your two favourite complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and consider the polynomial $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-2+i)(x-1-3i)$.

Comment: $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb R$ or not?

Comment: very sorry I had switched the polarities by mistake, the question is now correct I have got the answer which is $(2+i)$ and $(1-3i)$ but I need to know how to do the workings out, e.g when do I look out for a complex conjugate? how do I show on paper that I have established that there are complex conjugates to be found

Comment: @FlewittConnor I have edited your question to state that you mean real coefficients as that is a necessary condition for the roots to be as you say there are.

Comment: @gowrath i appreciate this however my exact question does not give this detail, it is from a maths problem sheet which does not specify that

Comment: @FlewittConnor then the question is incomplete. One can find infinitely many functions that satisfy the property of those two roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hint:  If $a, b, c, d, e \in \mathbb{R}$, then the complex roots of
>   $$ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0$$
>   come in *conjugate pairs*.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The other two solutions are: $2+i$ and $1-3i$. This a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra when $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Why should they? $(x-i)(x+i)(x-2+i)(x-3+i)$ is as good as any other polynomial of degree $4$.

Comment: Doesn't this assume real coefficients?

Comment: You are right:)

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't seem complete because you need to have some additional constraints on the coefficients of the polynomial for this to have one answer.

I am going to assume your question means $a, b, c, d, e \in \mathbb{R}$. In this case, since it is a 4th degree polynomial, it is of the form

$$
ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = (x-z_1)(x-z_2)(x - z_3)(x - z_4)
$$

where $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ are the roots of the polynomial. We already know two of these so we have:

$$
\begin{align}
z_1 &= 2 - i \\
z_3 &= 1 + 3i 
\end{align}
$$

Now since the coefficients are real, the roots must come in [conjugate pairs](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Conjugate_pair) i.e. for every complex root $z = \alpha+\beta i$, there must be another root $\overline{z} = \alpha - \beta i$ so that $(x-z)(x-\overline{z})$ will cancel out their imaginary parts, resulting in real coefficients. Thus:

$$
\begin{align}
z_2 &= \overline{z_1} = 2 + i \\
z_4 &= \overline{z_3} = 1 - 3i \\
\end{align}
$$

So your polynomial is:

$$
\begin{align}
ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e &= (x-z_1)(x-z_2)(x - z_3)(x - z_4)  \\
&= (x- 2 + i)(x- 2 - i)(x - 1 - 3i)(x - 1 + 3i) \\
&= x^4 - 6 x^3 + 23 x^2 - 50 x + 50
\end{align}
$$

Matching coefficients on the LHS and RHS, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
a &= 1 \\
b &= -6\\
c &= 23\\
d &= -50 \\
e &= 50
\end{align}
$$